# Sed remove time stamp from file with regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to delete a pattern from an html file. The time stamp consist of a 1-2 digit number a four letter word and then the word ago

example:

```
25 mins ago
```

or:

```
1 hour ago
```

and so on. I've tried using sed like this:

```
sed -i "s/([0-9]{1,2}) [a-z]* ago//g"
```

Sed does nothing, i'm not sure if my regex is wrong or if I am not escaping characters the right way.

Edit: I fixed that expression by removing an extra space, thanks choroba. Now sed removes mos of the text from the file. The expression needs to be less greedy? should also mention that ever time stamp is surrounded by `> <`
example:

```
>1 hour ago<
```

Edit: This is what worked for me. Thanks ravoori.

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\{,2\} [[:alpha:]]\{4,5\} ago//g'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are two spaces after `*`.

Comment: thanks, that helped? it deleted all of the text from the file. Any ideas on how to make this less greedy?

Comment: What does an example file look like and whats the expected result after the command is run?

Comment: What you want to retain after you run the sed command on the expression ? Do you want to keep the `><` and delete the characters in the middle ?

Comment: Its an HTML file. I expect it to remove ay charecters that match 1-2 didgits followed by hours or mins and then followed by ago.

Comment: is the position of the number fixed? then awk might give a better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below. You need to escape the quantifier metacharacters `{` and `}` with `sed`

```
echo "1 hour ago" | sed  's/[0-9]\{,2\} [[:alpha:]]\{4\} ago//g'
```

Comment: Thank you this worked like a charm, i had to edit it a bit sed -i and 

make it {4,5} because i'm an idiot and forgot that hours is 5 letters long. Thanks!

Comment: sed -i 's/[0-9]\{,2\} [[:alpha:]]\{4,5\} ago//g'

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "1 hour ago" | sed -e 's/.*ago$//g'
```

or

```
 sed -e 's/.*ago$//g' <filename>
```

This should remove any line that ends with `ago` in `filename`

You may not want to use this if you have other lines than just the timestamp that ends with `ago`. You didn't specify.

Comment: That wont do, it this needs to be dynamic, it has to range from 1 minute to 59 and 1 hour to 24

Comment: so you want to delete `Hello ago` too?

Comment: @almyz125 : `*` in front of ago takes care of any character. As the OP pointed out, it will also remove `whatever string ago` as well. So range from 1-60 minutes or hour from 1-24 shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Got ya. but wont that remove every character in my file before ago? I should also mention that ever time stamp is surrounded by >Time Stamp Here<.

Comment: @almyz125 : You have to be more specific in your question in order to get a more specific answer.